# Gnuplot Cannot open script file 'test.rtf'

Tags: gnuplot

I haven't found anything to my specific Problem with Gnuplot in other Threads. I want to load a text file on Mac. When I tell Gnuplot to

```
load '/Users/name/Desktop/test.rtf'
```

it always says `Cannot open script file`.

I already made sure, that I'm in the right working directory (I guess):

```
pwd
```

gives `/Users/name`

The text file contains:

```
plot sin(x)
```

and the standard terminal I'm using is

```
terminal type is wxt 0 enhanced
```

I hope someone can help me with that, since I'm not experienced in using programs with the terminal, so I really don't know how to solve my Problem right here.

Comment: From the file name it sounds as it is not a pure text file; `.rtf` indicates a mark-up. Can you post the file (or parts of it) in plain text?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35216823/2604213

Answer (score 0):

first of all thanks for your answer! So I just managed to find my mistake, it seems that it has to do something with the notation, since I'm working on a german Mac. So

```
load 'file'
```

makes Problems, while

```
load "file"
```

works fine for me. Unfortunately I still have the Problem, that

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced
set output "/Users/name/Desktop/testplot 2.png"
set encoding default

p sin(x)

set terminal wxt 0 enhanced
```

gives me a file, that can't be opened and it says the file is probably damaged or the format is not supported by 'preview'. It is not a huge problem actually since I can save the plot manually from the wxt terminal, but I really don't understand what Gnuplot is doing on OS X...

Comment: What are you doing? ;) Postscript terminal, but png file extension?

Comment: I actually don't really know what the postscript terminal is about. So thanks for your hint, I should start reading about the terminal to understand why it's even nonsense to save the file as .png ^^

Comment: Use `set terminal pngcairo; set output 'file.png'; plot sin(x); set output` to get started. The semicolons are necessary only if you have several commands on a single line (I cannot write it other way in a comment). You can omit them if you have every command on a separate line.